# Tring to make an RSI indicator that works on different time scales in Pine script

Tags: pine-script, trading

Ok so my code is this:

```
rsilength = input(14, title="RSI Length", type=input.integer)
//200 SMA
sma = sma(close, input(200))
rsiset = rsi(close, rsilength)
rsiW = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", rsiset)  // 1 Week
rsiD = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", rsiset)  // 1 Day
rsi4h = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", rsiset) // 4h

if rsi4h == rsiset
    sma := sma(close, input(1200))
if rsiD == rsiset
    sma := sma(close, input(200))
if rsiW == rsiset
    sma := sma(close, input(29))
```

I'm trying to have the sma plot appear correctly on the daily,4h and weekly chart.

It's working. The SMA line plots just fine on all 3 timeframes. But I get a warning

> The function 'sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

Is there a way to write the same thing and not get the warning?
The RSI also work just fine (I use them further down the code. Only thing that bothers me is those 3 warnings for each sma in the ifs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

var int     myInput = 1

rsilength   = input(14, title="RSI Length", type=input.integer)

sma         = sma(close, input(200))

rsiset      = rsi(close, rsilength)
rsiW        = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W",   rsiset) // 1 Week
rsiD        = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D",   rsiset) // 1 Day
rsi4h       = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", rsiset) // 4h

if rsi4h == rsiset
    myInput := input(1200, "input rsi4h")
else if rsiD == rsiset
    myInput := input( 200, "input rsiD")
else if rsiW == rsiset
    myInput := input(  29, "input rsiW")

sma := sma(close, myInput)

plot(sma)
```

Comment: I see that you set rsilength   = input(20).
I had it set up higher and neglected to add it in my code. Sorry about that.
Will fix it now.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your `rsilength` input parameter.